# How to use Framework 7 with Vue without framework7-vue

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I am newbie and want to use framework7 2.0.2 with vue-webpack boilerplate template. any ideas?

when I run dev server the chrome shows a blank page without any error, however when i change to and
it shows the content of a vue controller.

Looking for help.
my main.js code is like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue’
import 'framework7/dist/js/framework7’
import 'framework7/dist/css/framework7.css’
import Routes from './routes.js’
import App from ‘./App’
/* eslint-disable no-new /
// Init App
new Vue({
el: ‘#app’,
template: ‘’,
// Init Framework7 by passing parameters here
framework7: {
/ id: ‘io.framework7.testapp’, /
root: ‘#app’,
/ Uncomment to enable Material theme: material: true, */
material: true,
theme: ‘md’,
routes: Routes
},
// Register App Component
components: {
app: App
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

framework7-vue is not a must for vue, its only a wrapper. Beside its better to use wihtout vue because provides more options.

You can use these boilerplates, that guys makes very good templates as far as I see

https://github.com/pvtallulah/base-vue-f7v2-template
f7 v2

https://github.com/pvtallulah/base-vue-f7-webpack-cordova
f7 v1

Answer (score -1):

There is a starter template available using these instructions:

https://framework7.io/vue/templates.html

This will require you to clone the git repository, so you may need to go and read up on how this is done if you are new to it:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

If you get all this set up correctly, you should get a running app out of the box. Good luck.